# Page action gets executed before component's controller

Tags: visualforce

I have page

```
<apex:page controller="myController1" action="{!actionmethod}">

<c:compo value="hello"></c:compo> 

</apex:page>
```

Controller mycontroller1 class code is below

```
public with sharing class myController1 {

public void actionmethod()

{
system.debug('ACTIONMETHOD');
}
}
```

My component compo is as below

```
<apex:component controller="compocontroller">
<apex:attribute name="value" type="string" description="tu" assignTo="{!valueclassvar}"/>
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
  This is your new Component
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:component>
```

Its controller compocontroller is

```
 public class compocontroller   
    {
    public  string valueclassvar
  {
    get{
        system.debug('getmethod '+valueclassvar); 
        return valueclassvar;
        }
     set{ 
        system.debug('setmethodfirst'+ valueclassvar);
        valueclassvar = value;
        system.debug('setmethod'+ valueclassvar);
  }
       }

public compocontroller()
{    
system.debug('componentconstructor');
system.debug( valueclassvar);
}

}
```

Now issue is as per order of execution of VF page i expected first constructors of controllers/ext controllers to execute first followed by component's constructor if any.Then only action method/experession/getset(in randomn order) gets  priority

When i look at debug log for this code,i can see action method getting executed soon after constructor of main class why is that so?Debug log is

```
30.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
11:11:30.042 (42146795)|EXECUTION_STARTED
11:11:30.042 (42206001)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|066i0000004EBS1|VF: /apex/orderofexe
11:11:30.059 (59813931)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01pi0000005tsxw|myController1 <init>
11:11:30.059 (59842210)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
11:11:30.060 (60713868)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01pi0000005tsxw|myController1.myController1()
11:11:30.060 (60797146)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
11:11:30.060 (60807508)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
11:11:30.060 (60819362)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|myController1
11:11:30.060 (60844660)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
11:11:30.060 (60863778)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
11:11:30.060 (60869452)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
11:11:30.060 (60872642)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
11:11:30.060 (60888145)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|myController1 <init>
11:11:30.060 (60977531)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01pi0000005tsxw|myController1 invoke(actionmethod)
11:11:30.061 (61027224)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
11:11:30.061 (61064073)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[6]|System.debug(ANY)
11:11:30.061 (61093925)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|ACTIONMETHOD
11:11:30.061 (61102290)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[6]|System.debug(ANY)
11:11:30.061 (61107804)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
11:11:30.061 (61141605)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|myController1 invoke(actionmethod)
11:11:30.061 (61190978)|VF_APEX_CALL|j_id0|{!actionmethod}|PageReference: none
11:11:30.067 (67208323)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01pi0000005trqA|compocontroller <init>
11:11:30.067 (67233044)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
11:11:30.067 (67306289)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01pi0000005trqA|compocontroller.compocontroller()
11:11:30.067 (67320158)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|compocontroller
11:11:30.067 (67376097)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[8]|System.debug(ANY)
11:11:30.067 (67418075)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|componentconstructor
11:11:30.067 (67427228)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[8]|System.debug(ANY)
11:11:30.067 (67442037)|METHOD_ENTRY|[9]|01pi0000005trqA|compocontroller.__sfdc_valueclassvar()
11:11:30.067 (67481727)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[4]|System.debug(ANY)
11:11:30.067 (67498526)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|getmethod null
11:11:30.067 (67505165)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[4]|System.debug(ANY)
11:11:30.067 (67514592)|METHOD_EXIT|[9]|01pi0000005trqA|compocontroller.__sfdc_valueclassvar()
11:11:30.067 (67522573)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[9]|System.debug(ANY)
11:11:30.067 (67527466)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|null
11:11:30.067 (67532135)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[9]|System.debug(ANY)
11:11:30.067 (67546445)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|compocontroller <init>
11:11:30.067 (67707938)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|compocontroller set(valueclassvar,hello)
11:11:30.067 (67717432)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
11:11:30.067 (67730382)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|compocontroller set(valueclassvar,hello)
11:11:30.067 (67801649)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[4]|System.debug(ANY)
11:11:30.067 (67810862)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|setmethodfirstnull
11:11:30.067 (67816332)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[4]|System.debug(ANY)
11:11:30.067 (67833047)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[4]|System.debug(ANY)
11:11:30.067 (67838803)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|setmethodhello
```

Answer (score 5):

One of the things you can do in the `apex:page` `action` is to return a different `PageReference` and so go to a new page without rendering the body of the `apex:page`. Given that possibility, it makes no sense to execute component constructors before that `action` is executed as that could well be wasted work.

Also as parts of pages can be conditionally rendered, it may be that the component constructor is only executed if the component is actually output which would not be discovered until much later in the page execution than the evaluation of the opening `apex:page` element.

Comment: I can understand your logic..but why the documentation says otherwise.http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_get_request.htm...flow chart here clearly says soon after constructors check whether component is there and go for its constructors

Comment: @sfdc99999 Yes I agree with you that http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_controller_get_request.htm says the component constructors should run first. You could use the "Was this information helpful?" section at the bottom of the documentation to flag that the documentation may be wrong: perhaps the code has been optimised further since the documentation was written? Presumably this is an academic point and your intended code will work whatever the execution order is?

Comment: yeah i am just learning whats the correct execution order.:)..