# System.EmailTemplateRenderException: Too many SOQL queries: 101 Exception

Tags: visualforce-component, email-template, apex-email-service

Facing **'System.EmailTemplateRenderException: Too many SOQL queries: 101'** exception while using visual-force email template with custom controllers.

Api - **Messaging.SingleEmailMessage templateInstance =
            Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(email template Id, user Id, record Id);**

Not able to figure out how SOQL is reached.
Any idea on same? 
Following is Debug log information :

```
  13:28:43.439 (1439878776)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 11 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 788 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 113000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10
```

Comment: Could you post your controllers code?

Comment: No, I cannot do that :(

Comment: According to my assumption, you're retrieving data inside a `for loop` using `SOQL` and then binding that data with email template followed by sending email. You should place `SOQL` query outside of `for loop` to avoid that error

Comment: Go through [Exception :Too many SOQL queries: 101](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000181404&language=en_US&type=1) and understand what causes issue since you cannot post the code

Comment: Yes, I am trying to figure out the issue using Limits.getQueries(), but this number is very less (6 SOQL out of 100)

Comment: @NeedhiS It's difficult to answer your question without looking at code

Comment: You are most likely using a SOQL statement within a loop. Without code its difficult to identify. Are you getting this error while running test class? If you are sure that the current code does not have SOQL within a loop, then it could be from triggers while inserting your test data

Comment: Thanks for the inputs :) I have figured the issue, I have nested components which is causing the exception.

Comment: Just to document, the above issue is similar / related to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34819/setter-executes-twice-when-attributes-are-defined-on-components